# Go - function returns datetime

Tags: function, go, return-type

I'm learning go language and I try create a function returns datetime.

Already I've code that works ([look online at play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/Ey11tXtNmH)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func getDatetime() time.Time {
    return time.Now()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(getDatetime())
}
```

But! I really don't know is it correct. My doubt is about type of a return of a getDatetime function (**time.Time**). Should it be string or something else?

---

Btw: sorry for simple question, I'm python developer since few years.

Comment: I've used reflect.TypeOf for determining type of the return.

Comment: What are you trying to do? returning `time.Time` is the right way, unless you need a string then you can return `time.Now().String()` or call `.Format(...)`.

Comment: It is working correctly, why do you have doubts? Btw. the correct way to find out the type is the documentation: http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Now

Comment: @Sleafar: why doubts? I think that functions can return just few types of data: int, float, strings etc. time.Time() is actually abstract for me. Thanks for pointing at manual. At this moment I know what they're writing there. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the caller of your function is expecting a string (like a UI) and intending to do string manipulation on returned value (which doesn't make much sense in the context of datetime), you should just return `time.Time`. Otherwise, your caller will have no access to the provided time-related functions like `time.After()`, `time.Before()`, `time.Equal()` etc.

Comment: As I mentioned in above comment, I think that return type of a function could be just int, float, string etc. If time.Time is completly correct, then I don't have any questions.